# Rails: Undefined method 'downcase_email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There're some similar problems like this:

> undefined method 'downcase_email' for `#<User:0x00007fa0353b2518>`

（sorry,I don't know how to describe it...)
error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#create
```

> undefined method `downcase_email' for # 
>       Extracted source (around line #23): 
>       26 @user = User.new(user_params) 
>          if @user.save 
>          @user.send_activation_email 
>          flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."

when I get into the signup-page, at first I want to create a new account.
However, it failed. And the error occurred.

fine...here's the user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
    before_save :downcase_email
    before_create :create_activation_digest

    class << self
        def send_activation_email
            UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now 
        end

        private
        def downcase_email
            self.email=email.downcase
        end
        def create_activation_digest
            self.activation_token=User.new_token
            self.activation_digest=User.digest(activation_token)
        end   
    end  
end
```

and here's the user controller

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new' 
    end  
end
```

and the error seems like aiming at the @user.save.
plz...help me

Comment: you forgot to tell us what was the error.

Comment: Also please spend some effort and format the code properly (indented with two spaces, no weird chars on empty lines). As it is posted now, it's not valid ruby.

Comment: I don't know how to show the error.

Comment: what do you mean, just add it to the question, instead of comments.

Comment: What is that `class << self` doing there?

Comment: using it to define generation token and Summary of Methods

Comment: Do you know what it does? I don't think you read it in the rails tutorial. (as noted by fool-dev, you don't need it)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
```

and you don't need this method on your model after adding above line like

```
def downcase_email
    self.email=email.downcase
end
```

When the email is nil then it will show

> NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

```
nil.downcase
# NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

"As".downcase
#=> "as"
```

**If you do not agree to change like above then reformat model like below**

What is `class << self` you can remove this class and reformat your model like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
    before_save :downcase_email
    before_create :create_activation_digest

    def send_activation_email
        UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now 
    end

    private
    def downcase_email
        self.email = email.downcase
    end
    def create_activation_digest
        self.activation_token = User.new_token
        self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end   
end
```

Comment: Ah, I see. He misplaced the method. Thanks for reformatting his code. :) You were right all along, it seems. 